# Event gets called before it should

Tags: javascript, algorithm, events

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu. The way its built is as follows: If the menu got clicked on, it will fire a function that adds the class `open`. CSS will then handle the opening. It will then add a click event to `window`, which when fired, will remove the `open` class, then remove the window event, as it's no longer needed till the next menu click event.

The problem is, when the menus click event gets fired, the window click event gets fired as well, even though its event only gets added after a click. Here's an example: (It isn't the dropdown menu, because I figured it's unnecessary code. The algorithm is the same, though.)

How can I make the window click event get added after the menu click event, so it won't get called on the click event? (Also, if my algorithm doesn't make sense, please post one that does.)

#### JSFiddle

```js
var something = document.getElementById('something');

something.addEventListener('click', somethingClick);

function somethingClick() {
  console.log('something got clicked');

  window.addEventListener('click', windowClick);
}


function windowClick() {
  console.log('window got clicked');

  window.removeEventListener('click', windowClick);
}
```

```css
#something {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="something"></div>
```

Comment: Add `e.stopPropagation()` to `somethingClick` to prevent the original click to bubble up to the window. See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m6nLfhv8/).

Comment: @Teemu Thanks! that works. Do you want to post that as an answer, or should I accept the existing answer (which is based on your comment)?

Comment: Please accept Richard's answer, most likely he could had given the same answer without my comment too.

Comment: @Teemu Wow. Really honest of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is correct, just showing you how to implement.

```js
var something = document.getElementById('something');

something.addEventListener('click', somethingClick);

function somethingClick(event) { // <-- Added event
  event.stopPropagation(); // <-- prevent bubbling up to window
  console.log('something got clicked');

  window.addEventListener('click', windowClick);
}


function windowClick() {
  console.log('window got clicked');

  window.removeEventListener('click', windowClick);
}
```

```css
#something {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="something"></div>
```